# Assign Key Field Value Only If Corresponding Lookup Result value Exist

Tags: delphi

I have ten master tables and one Transaction table. In my transaction table (it is a memory table just like ClientDataSet) there are ten lookup fields pointing to my ten master tables.

Now i am trying to dynamically assigning key field values to all my lookup key field values (of the transaction table) from a different Server(data is coming as a soap xml). Before assigning these values i need to check whether the corresponding result value is valid in master tables or not. I am using a filter (eg status = 1 ) to check whether it is valid or not.

Currently how we are doing is, before assigning each key field value we are filtering the master tables using this filter and using the locate function to check whether it is there or not. and if located we will assign its key field value.

This will work fine if there is only few records in my master tables. Consider my master tables having fifty thousand records each (yeah, customer is having so much data), this will lead to big performance issue.

Could you please help me to handle this situation.

Thanks 
Basil

Comment: I don't see any other option if you use lookup fields which rely on a DataSet. You could query the DB directly rather than locate it in a DataSet. The lookup value could be a result of a JOIN query. very hard to answer this Q, because I don't know what the Transaction table usage (can You add/edit/delete from it?).

Comment: Yes user can edit the transaction table. It is a TDBISAMTable component. Just like TClientDataSet

Comment: I think you're going to have to run some test cases using your various methods to determine which will provide the best performance based on your design.  You could try using queries for the master tables, querying each using the key and if query.recordcount > 0 then the key exists, and compare this to your Filter/locate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know if it is slow, why, where, and what solution works best is to profile.
Don't make a priori assumptions.

That being said, minimizing round trips to the server and the amount of data transferred is often a good thing to try.
For instance, if your master tables are on the server (not 100% clear from your question), sending only 1 Query (or stored proc call) passing all the values to check at once as parameters and doing a bunch of "IF EXISTS..." and returning all the answers at once (either output params or a 1 record dataset) would be a good start.

And 50,000 records is not much, so, as I said initially, you may not even have a performance problem. Check it first!